# Чтение поля содержащего реализации интерфейса

Tags: java, yaml

У меня есть объект с полем:

```
public List<Mod> mods;
```

*Mod* это интерфейс. Есть несколько классов, реализующих его.

Мой yaml выглядит так:

```
mods:
  mod1: # Идентификатор мода
    id: "Yaml test" # Данные мода
  mod2:
    type: SEMI
```

Идентификатор не совпадает с названием класса

Как я могу эффективно прочитать этот объект?

Comment: Я задал другой вопрос, который помог мне в решении, [вот ссылка на него](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1562049/Чтение-поля-с-типом-интерфейс-с-помощью-jackson).

Answer (score 1):

Фактически содержимое `yaml`-файла соответствует не списку, а словарю (мапе) `Map<String, Mod> mods`, поэтому для решения данной проблемы есть два способа:

1. Изменить Java-код, чтобы он соответствовал формату `yaml`-файла.
   Тогда можно будет извлечь *коллекцию значений* из словаря/мапы при помощи стандартного метода [`Map::values`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--):

```java
public Map<String, Mod> mods; // List<Mod> -> Map<String, Mod>

public List<Mod> modsAsList() {
    return mods == null ? null : new ArrayList<>(mods.values());
}
```

2. Изменить структуру `yaml`-файла, чтобы она соответствовала списку `List<Mod>` (например, ключи `mod1`, `mod2` станут комментариями):

```yaml
mods:
  -
    #mod1
    id: Yaml test
  -
    #mod2
    type: SEMI
```

---

***Обновление***

Если требуется получить словарь *классов экземпляров `Mod`* на основании данных из `yaml`-файла, то следует создать новый экземпляр словаря с соответствующей типизацией и сгенерировать его на основании словаря `Map<String, Mod>`, используя к примеру "ленивую" загрузку:

```java
public Map<String, Mod> mods; // первый вариант решения

private Map<String, Class<? extends Mod>> modClasses;

public Map<String, Class<? extends Mod>> getModClasses() {
    if (modClasses == null && mods != null) {
        modClasses = mods.entrySet()
            .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Mod>>
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().getClass()
            ));
    }
    return modClasses;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я бы хотел с помощью этих ключей определять какой модуль описывается. Например создать поле Map<String, Class<? extends Mod>> с помощью которого я могу получать классы модов от их идентификатора, тем самым понимать какой мод описывается. Так же хочу отметить, что у меня не может быть 2 одинаковых мода(что устраняет проблему совпадающих ключей).

Comment: @Z3koR, смотрите обновление в ответе.

Comment: Теперь имея поле `Map<String, Class<? extends Mod>>` в моем загрузчике, я хочу прочитать `List<Mod>` (по факту мне не нужен идентификатор) из моего yaml.

Comment: Который `String` у тебя в мапе) Извини, если плохо объясняю.